# Azure DevOps invoked from an API to lauch a Terraform file

Tags: azure, api, devops, serverless

Based on the following design I want to launch a Terraform file and an application code on Azure DevOps when an Azure Functions trigger the Pipeline.

- Do you know any example to do a normal API REST Call to A. Dev Ops?
  (using Python or JS)
- Do you think it is a good strategy to generate an orchestration pipeline to make the workflow of the infrastructure and later on the application code?
- In order to deploy the application
  code, how can I modify it using the arguments coming from the API?

[architecture design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JucHl.png)

Comment: You can work with azure-devops

Comment: That is the option I have in mind. However, how can I trigger an Azure Pipeline from an Azure Functions passing arguments that should be used in the Continuous Deployment? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can via API, try to google it and if you still have questions feel free to hit me

Comment: I have modified the post description adding requirements and an architecture design.